# Clarification regarding oozie launcher jobs

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I needed some clarifications regarding the oozie launcher job.

1) Is the launcher job launched per workflow application (with several actions) or per action within a workflow application?

2) Use Case: I have workflows that contain multiple `shell` actions (which internally execute spark, hive, pig actions etc.). The reason for using `shell` is because additional parameters like partition date can be computed using custom logic and passed to hive using .q files

Example Shell File:

```
hive -hiveconf DATABASE_NAME=$1 -hiveconf MASTER_TABLE_NAME=$2 -hiveconf SOURCE_TABLE_NAME=$3 -hiveconf -f $4
```

Example .q File:

```
use ${hiveconf:DATABASE_NAME};
insert overwrite into table ${hiveconf:MASTER_TABLE_NAME} select * from ${hiveconf:SOURCE_TABLE_NAME};
```

I set the `oozie.launcher.mapreduce.job.queuename` and `mapreduce.job.queuename` to different queues to avoid starvation of task slots in a single queue. I also omitted the `<capture-output></capture-output>` in the corresponding `shell` action. However, I still see the launcher job occupying a lot of memory from the launcher queue.

- Is this because the launcher job caches the log ouput that comes from hive?
- Is it necessary to give the launcher job enough memory when executing a shell action the way I am?
- What would happen if I explicitly limited the launcher job memory?

I would highly appreciate it if someone could outline the responsibilities of the oozie launcher job.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is the launcher job launched per workflow application (with several actions) or per action within a workflow application?

The launcher job is launched per action in the workflow.

I would highly recommend you to use respective oozie actions, Hive, Pig etc. Because it allows oozie to handle your workflow and actions in a better manner.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please elaborate on how is it better? I mean other than the configurations that need to be set explicitly in a shell action (perhaps properties like oozie.hive.defaults and the like) are there any gains from the perspective of yarn queue memory consumption?